How to vertically append two longtblr?
I have two longtblr(or so called panels, for the research reason, it should be put together to illstruate some conclusion with one caption). However, their colspec is quiet different.
With the framework of tabularray, two longtblr is float, is there easy/elegant way to append two longtblrs without burden(I want a method to append 10 longtblrs with different colspecs elegantly)?
Here below is the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}  
\newcommand*{\tabA}{
    Panel A: Sample selection of site visits &  \\
     & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\
    & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\
}

\newcommand*{\tabB}{
    Panel B: The number of analysts and managers in each joint site visit &  &  &  &  \\
    Year & Avg. of broker & Avg. of analyst & Avg. of fund company & Avg. of fund manager \\
     & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
    2007 & 1.266 & 1.422 & 1.844 & 1.953 \\
    2008 & 1.524 & 1.866 & 2.049 & 2.159 \\
    2009 & 1.568 & 1.773 & 1.886 & 1.955 \\
    2010 & 1.555 & 1.684 & 1.787 & 1.865 \\
    2011 & 1.550 & 1.814 & 1.664 & 1.750 \\
    2012 & 2.257 & 2.693 & 2.171 & 2.491 \\
    2013 & 2.345 & 2.782 & 2.243 & 2.601 \\
    2014 & 2.433 & 2.887 & 2.487 & 2.809 \\
    2015 & 2.391 & 2.897 & 2.598 & 2.976 \\
    2016 & 2.748 & 3.360 & 2.366 & 2.702 \\
    2017 & 3.314 & 4.055 & 2.344 & 2.695 \\
    2018 & 3.835 & 4.648 & 3.094 & 3.824 \\
    2019 & 3.430 & 4.221 & 3.008 & 3.865 \\
    2020 & 2.907 & 3.931 & 4.970 & 6.973 \\
    2021 & 3.330 & 4.314 & 5.540 & 7.143 \\
    Avg. & 2.430 & 2.957 & 2.670 & 3.184 \\
    2007 & 1.266 & 1.422 & 1.844 & 1.953 \\
    2008 & 1.524 & 1.866 & 2.049 & 2.159 \\
    2009 & 1.568 & 1.773 & 1.886 & 1.955 \\
    2010 & 1.555 & 1.684 & 1.787 & 1.865 \\
    2011 & 1.550 & 1.814 & 1.664 & 1.750 \\
    2012 & 2.257 & 2.693 & 2.171 & 2.491 \\
    2013 & 2.345 & 2.782 & 2.243 & 2.601 \\
    2014 & 2.433 & 2.887 & 2.487 & 2.809 \\
    2015 & 2.391 & 2.897 & 2.598 & 2.976 \\
    2016 & 2.748 & 3.360 & 2.366 & 2.702 \\
    2017 & 3.314 & 4.055 & 2.344 & 2.695 \\
    2018 & 3.835 & 4.648 & 3.094 & 3.824 \\
    2019 & 3.430 & 4.221 & 3.008 & 3.865 \\
    2020 & 2.907 & 3.931 & 4.970 & 6.973 \\
    2021 & 3.330 & 4.314 & 5.540 & 7.143 \\
    Avg. & 2.430 & 2.957 & 2.670 & 3.184 \\
    2007 & 1.266 & 1.422 & 1.844 & 1.953 \\
    2008 & 1.524 & 1.866 & 2.049 & 2.159 \\
    2009 & 1.568 & 1.773 & 1.886 & 1.955 \\
    2010 & 1.555 & 1.684 & 1.787 & 1.865 \\
    2011 & 1.550 & 1.814 & 1.664 & 1.750 \\
    2012 & 2.257 & 2.693 & 2.171 & 2.491 \\
    2013 & 2.345 & 2.782 & 2.243 & 2.601 \\
    2014 & 2.433 & 2.887 & 2.487 & 2.809 \\
    2015 & 2.391 & 2.897 & 2.598 & 2.976 \\
    2016 & 2.748 & 3.360 & 2.366 & 2.702 \\
    2017 & 3.314 & 4.055 & 2.344 & 2.695 \\
    2018 & 3.835 & 4.648 & 3.094 & 3.824 \\
    2019 & 3.430 & 4.221 & 3.008 & 3.865 \\
    2020 & 2.907 & 3.931 & 4.970 & 6.973 \\
    2021 & 3.330 & 4.314 & 5.540 & 7.143 \\
    Avg. & 2.430 & 2.957 & 2.670 & 3.184 \\
    Avg. & 2.430 & 2.957 & 2.670 & 3.184 \\
    2007 & 1.266 & 1.422 & 1.844 & 1.953 \\
    2008 & 1.524 & 1.866 & 2.049 & 2.159 \\
    2009 & 1.568 & 1.773 & 1.886 & 1.955 \\
    2010 & 1.555 & 1.684 & 1.787 & 1.865 \\
    2011 & 1.550 & 1.814 & 1.664 & 1.750 \\
    2012 & 2.257 & 2.693 & 2.171 & 2.491 \\
    2013 & 2.345 & 2.782 & 2.243 & 2.601 \\
    2014 & 2.433 & 2.887 & 2.487 & 2.809 \\
    2015 & 2.391 & 2.897 & 2.598 & 2.976 \\
    2016 & 2.748 & 3.360 & 2.366 & 2.702 \\
    2017 & 3.314 & 4.055 & 2.344 & 2.695 \\
    2018 & 3.835 & 4.648 & 3.094 & 3.824 \\
    2019 & 3.430 & 4.221 & 3.008 & 3.865 \\
    2020 & 2.907 & 3.931 & 4.970 & 6.973 \\
    2021 & 3.330 & 4.314 & 5.540 & 7.143 \\
    Avg. & 2.430 & 2.957 & 2.670 & 3.184 \\
}
\begin{longtblr}[
    expand = \tabA,
    ]{
        rowhead = 2,
        cell{1}{1} = {c=2,r=1}{l},
        width = 1.0\linewidth,
        cells = {c,m,font=\tiny},
        colspec = {X[l,7cm]X[l,2cm]},
        stretch = 0.6,
        rowsep = 0.6pt,
        hlines,vlines,
        hspan = minimal, 
}
\tabA
\end{longtblr}
\begin{longtblr}[
    expand = \tabB,
    ]{
    rowhead = 2,    
    cell{1}{1} = {c=5,r=1}{l},
    width = 1.0\linewidth,
    cells = {c,m,font=\tiny},
    colspec = {X[c,0.5cm]X[c,1.8cm]X[c,1.8cm]X[c,2.3cm]X[c,2.3cm]},
    stretch = 0.6,
    rowsep = 0.6pt,
    hlines,vlines,
    hspan = minimal,
}
\tabB
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}


An real example of many panels as below:


How should the transition between the first and second table look like? Repeat the first caption? A bit of space? No space at all?

It can be achieved by merging the cells with patience, but it's troublesome to toggle the QUITE DIFFERENT colspec.

The Transition could be a bit of space or no space at all. Emm, maybe I can provide an Not Longtblr one(append to the original question)

If you'd choose a professional looking table layout without vertical lines (and use at least one flexible width column), then your captions would correspond to the "Panel A:" etc. from your example image. The spacing above and below can be adjusted with presep and postsep.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz isn't the caption meant to be e.g. Table I or whatever? or are you saying it would be better to make the Panel A etc. the captions? (I'm not very familiar with tabularray - I've used it, but only for answers and only a tiny bit.)

You can certainly change the caption to read Panel A.  Alternatively you could have this as the first line of your table.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz what I mean both of two panels should be put together as a WHOTE float table, which shares the same caption like Table1: some result as @cfr's comment. The difficulity I confronted with is that I need the propreties provided by longtblr, and I also don't want them float as \begin{longtblr} and \end{longtblr}, I want to put many longtables(as the tabular, which is NOT float) together as if a "outer" table environment somehow.

table is a float. if you don't want a float, don't use table ;). the capt-of or caption packages can give you captions outside of floats.

what do the red boxes indicate? I don't really understand what you want it to look like.

@cfr the red boxes just to show that each panel has the properties of longtblr.

but is that good i.e. it should look like that or bad i.e. it shouldn't?

You could use https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=6804 to remove the automatic caption before the second table and then remove the space between the tables:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewTblrTheme{clean}{
  \DefTblrTemplate{caption}{clean}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{caption}{clean}
}

\begin{document}  
\newcommand*{\tabA}{
    Panel A: Sample selection of site visits &  \\
     & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\
    & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\ & No. of Total IR Activities \\
    1.Total IR activities & 99,605 \\
    2.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts & 43,450 \\
    3.The IR activities involving mutual fund managers & 24,393 \\
    4.The IR activities involving sell-side analysts and mutual fund managers & 19,323 \\
    Site visit & 17,870 \\
    Analyst meeting, Road show, and other meetings initiated by sell-side analysts & 1,116 \\
    Performance announcement meeting, Public news meeting, Media interview, and Others & 597 \\
}

\newcommand*{\tabB}{
    Panel B: The number of analysts and managers in each joint site visit &  &  &  &  \\
    Year & Avg. of broker & Avg. of analyst & Avg. of fund company & Avg. of fund manager \\
     & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
    2007 & 1.266 & 1.422 & 1.844 & 1.953 \\
    2008 & 1.524 & 1.866 & 2.049 & 2.159 \\
    2009 & 1.568 & 1.773 & 1.886 & 1.955 \\
    2010 & 1.555 & 1.684 & 1.787 & 1.865 \\
    2011 & 1.550 & 1.814 & 1.664 & 1.750 \\
    2012 & 2.257 & 2.693 & 2.171 & 2.491 \\
    2013 & 2.345 & 2.782 & 2.243 & 2.601 \\
    2014 & 2.433 & 2.887 & 2.487 & 2.809 \\
    2015 & 2.391 & 2.897 & 2.598 & 2.976 \\
    2016 & 2.748 & 3.360 & 2.366 & 2.702 \\
    2017 & 3.314 & 4.055 & 2.344 & 2.695 \\
    2018 & 3.835 & 4.648 & 3.094 & 3.824 \\
    2019 & 3.430 & 4.221 & 3.008 & 3.865 \\
    2020 & 2.907 & 3.931 & 4.970 & 6.973 \\
    2021 & 3.330 & 4.314 & 5.540 & 7.143 \\
    Avg. & 2.430 & 2.957 & 2.670 & 3.184 \\
    2007 & 1.266 & 1.422 & 1.844 & 1.953 \\
    2008 & 1.524 & 1.866 & 2.049 & 2.159 \\
    2009 & 1.568 & 1.773 & 1.886 & 1.955 \\
    2010 & 1.555 & 1.684 & 1.787 & 1.865 \\
    2011 & 1.550 & 1.814 & 1.664 & 1.750 \\
    2012 & 2.257 & 2.693 & 2.171 & 2.491 \\
    2013 & 2.345 & 2.782 & 2.243 & 2.601 \\
    2014 & 2.433 & 2.887 & 2.487 & 2.809 \\
    2015 & 2.391 & 2.897 & 2.598 & 2.976 \\
    2016 & 2.748 & 3.360 & 2.366 & 2.702 \\
    2017 & 3.314 & 4.055 & 2.344 & 2.695 \\
    2018 & 3.835 & 4.648 & 3.094 & 3.824 \\
    2019 & 3.430 & 4.221 & 3.008 & 3.865 \\
    2020 & 2.907 & 3.931 & 4.970 & 6.973 \\
    2021 & 3.330 & 4.314 & 5.540 & 7.143 \\
    Avg. & 2.430 & 2.957 & 2.670 & 3.184 \\
    2007 & 1.266 & 1.422 & 1.844 & 1.953 \\
    2008 & 1.524 & 1.866 & 2.049 & 2.159 \\
    2009 & 1.568 & 1.773 & 1.886 & 1.955 \\
    2010 & 1.555 & 1.684 & 1.787 & 1.865 \\
    2011 & 1.550 & 1.814 & 1.664 & 1.750 \\
    2012 & 2.257 & 2.693 & 2.171 & 2.491 \\
    2013 & 2.345 & 2.782 & 2.243 & 2.601 \\
    2014 & 2.433 & 2.887 & 2.487 & 2.809 \\
    2015 & 2.391 & 2.897 & 2.598 & 2.976 \\
    2016 & 2.748 & 3.360 & 2.366 & 2.702 \\
    2017 & 3.314 & 4.055 & 2.344 & 2.695 \\
    2018 & 3.835 & 4.648 & 3.094 & 3.824 \\
    2019 & 3.430 & 4.221 & 3.008 & 3.865 \\
    2020 & 2.907 & 3.931 & 4.970 & 6.973 \\
    2021 & 3.330 & 4.314 & 5.540 & 7.143 \\
    Avg. & 2.430 & 2.957 & 2.670 & 3.184 \\
    Avg. & 2.430 & 2.957 & 2.670 & 3.184 \\
    2007 & 1.266 & 1.422 & 1.844 & 1.953 \\
    2008 & 1.524 & 1.866 & 2.049 & 2.159 \\
    2009 & 1.568 & 1.773 & 1.886 & 1.955 \\
    2010 & 1.555 & 1.684 & 1.787 & 1.865 \\
    2011 & 1.550 & 1.814 & 1.664 & 1.750 \\
    2012 & 2.257 & 2.693 & 2.171 & 2.491 \\
    2013 & 2.345 & 2.782 & 2.243 & 2.601 \\
    2014 & 2.433 & 2.887 & 2.487 & 2.809 \\
    2015 & 2.391 & 2.897 & 2.598 & 2.976 \\
    2016 & 2.748 & 3.360 & 2.366 & 2.702 \\
    2017 & 3.314 & 4.055 & 2.344 & 2.695 \\
    2018 & 3.835 & 4.648 & 3.094 & 3.824 \\
    2019 & 3.430 & 4.221 & 3.008 & 3.865 \\
    2020 & 2.907 & 3.931 & 4.970 & 6.973 \\
    2021 & 3.330 & 4.314 & 5.540 & 7.143 \\
    Avg. & 2.430 & 2.957 & 2.670 & 3.184 \\
}
\begin{longtblr}[
    expand = \tabA,
    caption={some caption},
    postsep=0pt
    ]{
%        rowhead = 2,
        cell{1}{1} = {c=2,r=1}{l},
        width = 1.0\linewidth,
        cells = {c,m,font=\tiny},
        colspec = {X[l]X[l,2cm]},
        stretch = 0.6,
        rowsep = 0.6pt,
        hlines,
        hspan = minimal, 
}
\tabA
\end{longtblr}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\begin{longtblr}[
    expand = \tabB,
    caption={some caption},    
    theme=clean,
    presep=0pt
    ]{
%    rowhead = 2,    
    cell{1}{1} = {c=5,r=1}{l},
    width = 1.0\linewidth,
    cells = {c,m,font=\tiny},
    colspec = {X[c]X[c,1.8cm]X[c,1.8cm]X[c,2.3cm]X[c,2.3cm]},
    stretch = 0.6,
    rowsep = 0.6pt,
    hlines,
    hspan = minimal,
    hline{1}={0pt},
}
\tabB
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}





Thanks to your patience, what I want is the TWO QUITE differerent longtblrs share with ONE caption like 'Table I:xxx' as below and @cfr's comments, that's to say it holds the structure as: 1. Whole Table Caption ;1.1 Panel longtblr; 1.2 Another Panel longtblr; 1.3 / 1.4 .... In your answer just change the transition, and don't put them together as a whole. I hope I make it clear.

I have attempted to put the Panel A and Panel B etc. as the caption in each longtblr, but it faced the same problem, if the research need to hyperref both two panel as a whole lile \label{fig: long panel}, it can't achieve the result.
